How to query the whole tree by `pid` and `path` fields?
Table
CREATE TABLE t_city(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  path varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  leaf BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
  pid INT NOT NULL,
  level INT NOT NULL,
  sort numeric(12,8)
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "unique_title" ON t_city(pid, name);
INSERT INTO t_city VALUES (1, 'New York State', '1', 'f', 0, 1, 2.00223000);
INSERT INTO t_city VALUES (2, 'New York City', '1,2', 'f', 1, 2, 2.00000000);
INSERT INTO t_city VALUES (3, 'Albany', '1,3', 'f', 1, 2, 1.04560000);
INSERT INTO t_city VALUES (6, 'Manhattan', '1,2,6', 'f', 2, 3, 5.00000000);
INSERT INTO t_city VALUES (7, 'Queens', '1,2,7', 'f', 2, 3, 1.00000000);
INSERT INTO t_city VALUES (4, 'The Bronx', '1.2,4', 'f', 2, 3, 12.00000000);
INSERT INTO t_city VALUES (5, 'Brooklyn', '1,2,5', 'f', 2, 3, 9.00000000);
INSERT INTO t_city VALUES (8, 'Staten Island', '1,2,8', 'f', 2, 3, 3.00000000);

I want to query to get the following json tree structure data:
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "New York State",
    "path": "1",
    "leaf": false,
    "pid": 0,
    "level": 1,
    "sort": 2.00223000,
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Albany",
        "path": "1,3",
        "leaf": true,
        "pid": 1,
        "level": 2,
        "sort": 1.04560000
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "New York City",
        "path": "1,2",
        "leaf": false,
        "pid": 1,
        "level": 2,
        "sort": 2.00000000,
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "Queens",
            "path": "1,2,7",
            "leaf": true,
            "pid": 2,
            "level": 3,
            "sort": 1.00000000
          },
          {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "Staten Island",
            "path": "1,2,8",
            "leaf": true,
            "pid": 2,
            "level": 3,
            "sort": 3.00000000
          },
          {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "Manhattan",
            "path": "1,2,6",
            "leaf": true,
            "pid": 2,
            "level": 3,
            "sort": 5.00000000
          },
          {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Brooklyn",
            "path": "1,2,5",
            "leaf": true,
            "pid": 2,
            "level": 3,
            "sort": 9.00000000
          },
          {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "The Bronx",
            "path": "1.2,4",
            "leaf": true,
            "pid": 2,
            "level": 3,
            "sort": 12.00000000
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]

This tree can be obtained through the pid or path field value. Sort nodes of the same level by the sort field.
I would have thought this was a common tree structure, but all I found in stack overflow were examples of tree structures that are unique.
As far as possible, queries for tables with path, pid fields can be used, rather than needing to specify the table's fields in the result set.
Recursion and extension can be used.
If it is possible to improve query performance, you can add fields.
Thanks.

I'm pretty sure, that you can't do it with a single query, because recursion and group by don't work together. I would do an sql stored procedure for it:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION city_to_json(city_id integer) RETURNS jsonb AS $$
 WITH recursive_children AS (
  SELECT p.id, array_to_json(array_agg(city_to_json(c.id)))::jsonb AS children
  FROM t_city p 
  LEFT JOIN t_city c ON p.id = c.pid 
  WHERE p.id = $1 
  GROUP BY p.id
 )
 SELECT jsonb_set(row_to_json(p)::jsonb, '{children}', g.children)
 FROM recursive_children g 
 JOIN  t_city p ON p.id = g.id;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

It's a recursive function, you can use it for any existing node – let it leaf, branch or root – like this:
select city_to_json(8);
-- or 
select city_to_json(1);

You can do the same in a procedural language (plpgsql, tcl, perl, ...), if it suits you better. There is also some work left done, like getin rid of the null-s (with or without the container children node) and limiting the recursion – like stopping at a circular recursion or you just don't want 100 level depth sometimes.
Adding a version for order as requested. Also removed the pointless order from the original (because at that point there is only one row, which we can't sort).
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION city_to_json(city_id integer) RETURNS jsonb AS $$
 WITH children_in_order AS (
 SELECT id,pid FROM t_city WHERE pid= CASE WHEN $1 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE $1 END ORDER BY sort),
 recursive_children AS (
  SELECT p.id, array_to_json(array_agg(city_to_json(c.id)))::jsonb AS children
  FROM t_city p 
  LEFT JOIN children_in_order c ON p.id = c.pid 
  WHERE p.id = CASE WHEN $1 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE $1 END 
  GROUP BY 1
 )
 SELECT jsonb_set(row_to_json(p)::jsonb, '{children}', g.children)
 FROM recursive_children g 
 JOIN  t_city p ON p.id = g.id
 ORDER BY p.path;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

select city_to_json(8);
-- or 
select city_to_json(0);


it's not working. result is empty.

Yes it does. Do you have data in your table? Did you get any error? Which pg? I tested it only with pg 14.12, though i don't think it's a version issue.

https://sqlfiddle.com/postgresql/online-compiler?id=e2a52f88-d205-4343-b24a-c9e479344a8f

Could you please add sorting based on sort field, and querying all nodes with pid of 0 instead of id of 1.
